# how to remove borders of jquery validationEngine error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using this line to show an error for inputs fields that do not meet the requirement

```
$(slider).slider().validationEngine('showPrompt', errorMsg, 'pass', 'bottomLeft', false);
```

my only problem though is I would like to remove the borders of the error message prompt. this is the reference I use most of the time for jquery (http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) but it does not show how to remove the error message borders.

using this though,

```
$(slider).slider().validationEngine('showPrompt', errorMsg);
```

would remove the border and just display the test BUT it would append another div and would mess up the layout because of the height of the additional divs for the error messages so I'm sticking with the path removing the border of the generated error message for the showPrompt function with 4 input parameters

Answer (score 0):

You dont mention if you want it gone on all popups or just a specific one. Assuming you want it gone on all, just add this in your `CSS`

```
 .formError .formErrorContent { 
           border:0px
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer using firebug the style of box-shadow needs to be manipulated to modify the border of the error messages

to add, this is a better approach

https://perishablepress.com/css3-remove-box-shadow/